# How do I display my germination rates? Is it count data? Not sure!

Tags: categorical-data, survival, mean

I have 4 treatments, each with 5 Petri dishes (so total 20), and each Petri dish has 25 seeds in it. I am looking to discuss how many seeds have germinated. Should I get the mean germination of each treatment and then discuss it as a percentage of 25 seeds? So if in the root treatment, 4,4,6,6,0 germinate, so my mean is an average of 5 seeds out of 25, how do I best display/discuss this?

---

```
> ARpetri<-read.table(file.choose(),header=TRUE)
> attach(ARpetri)
> names(ARpetri)
[1] "Distilled" "Marigold"  "Mixed"     "Root"     
> ARpetri
  Distilled Marigold Mixed Root
1         2        1     1    5
2         2        1     0    3
3         3        0     0    3
4         3        1     0    4
5         0        1     1    1
```

---

the counts on each row do not belong together, just the columns and the first column is excel generated and not my own. I hope that helps clarify. Many thanks for all the advice and I will definitely check out the R mailing list as suggested. Any recommendations for where I can look up how to create the plot pictured above? I think it would be useful to re-create with my other counts and "eyeball" the data. Thanks all!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model

Comment: "How many seeds germinated" is a count... how did you know how many there were? By counting them.

Comment: Could you have a fraction of a seed germinate??

Answer (score 4):

Your outcome is discrete insofar as the response can only assume values 0/25 (1/25) 25/25 or 0(0.04)1 or 0(4)100%, but in principle your rate is a probability. Had you used 250, 2500, ... seeds your response would have been more and more finely measured and it's fruitful (pun intended) to think that you're modelling a quantity on a continuous scale.

Tukey called numbers like 4/25 counted fractions, not that anyone really needs a special name.

GLM software that I know of will handle this properly as a model with binomial link and total 25. Display is not a problem as you have 20 counts which can be shown directly on a single graph with both count and probability or percent scales.

If you post the data, example analyses are likely to follow.

EDIT Some small questions remain about the data, but on the assumption that the row identifiers just arbitrarily label replicates, and have no other meaning, then this kind of plot shows all the information in the data. The horizontal lines show means.

Note that my software sorts Distilled Marigold Mixed Root alphabetically but it could be that there is a more meaningful order. I am not a plant scientist and in any case I guess that it needs the OP to explain here.

[image]

Comment: +1. There *always* are meaningful sequences that can be inferred from the data: order the groups by median, maximum, or variance, for instance. That's one no-cost way to add information to a graphic: it communicates more without costing any more ink.

Comment: Sure, and I would order by mean if these were my data and there was no reason otherwise. I am asking to hear from the OP whether there is a natural order.

Comment: Hi, I would probably go for mean as well but mostly because I am not fully versed in R and statistical models. The order of the treatments (distilled, marigold etc) doesn't matter in so far as the treatment is concerned. So would definitely need to order them in terms of a measure such as mean, which would visually be far more meaningful. Very appreciative of all the comments and any feedback on better content is appreciated as well as I am new to this community.

Comment: Just a quick point about the data: the column to the far left (1,2,3,4,5) is not included, it appeared in R when I attached the data that was in tabs delimited format after I added it to excel. So they are excel's row numbers.

Comment: Using R or anything else is immaterial here, as is my use of Stata: CV is not focused on which software or which code to use or how to use it. The  identifier was read as such by me. What you're leaving unclear is whether the identifiers identify plots or containers or other groups, e.g. whether the values in the  first row (observation) are linked in some sense. Please consider the graph redrawn so that treatments are ordered by mean.

Comment: Hi Nick, the first row (observation) are not linked. I'm confused about how you made that graph. Is that ok to ask about or not a question for this space?

Comment: It's using my own Stata program `stripplot`.But it's essentially a scatter plot with annotations, with the horizontal axis being based on treatment and rank order of response. R people are always telling me that R graphics are superior, so it should be trivial in R except I am not the person to ask how.